# hostname is different in vercel logs than what i have in env

Tags: mysql, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I'm using mysql2 to fetch some data from a MySQL database. On localhost, it's working without any errors, but on production, I'm not getting any data, instead I'm getting 504 error and in Vercel realtime logs, I'm getting `Access denied for user 'myusername'@'ec2-3-236-108-51.compute-1.amazonaws.com'`. That hostname is totally different than what I have in my `.env` file.

In .env file I have `NEXT_PUBLIC_DB_HOSTNAME=host.example.com`, then i'm using like this:

```
const dbConnection = await mysql.createConnection({
    user: myusername,
    host: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DB_HOSTNAME,
    rest of code ...
```

If I'm doing something like this, just to console.log() the hostname, the output is correct on localhost & production, but on vercel logs, i'm geting that hostname totally different than what I have.

```
const hostname = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DB_HOSTNAME;
console.log(`The hostname for the database is: ${hostname}`);

// OUTPUT is host.example.com on localhost and production
```

Is this something related to security? On Vercel App Settings, don't have any environment variables added.

Comment: I know is a bad practice, but the only solution was to add to Remote MySQL `%.%.%.%` because vercel deployments use dynamic IP.